# Allow data structure to be converted to array using Array.from

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

Say I have a class like so:

```
class Foo {

 constructor(){
  this.internalList = new Set([1,2,3])
 }

}
```

is there some method I can implement like so:

```
class Foo {

 constructor(){
  this.internalList = new Set([1,2,3])
 }

 toArray(){   // add this method

     const ret = [];
     for(const v of this.internalList){
         ret.push(v);
     }
     return ret;
  }

}
```

so that I can call this:

```
  const v = Array.from(new Foo());
```

so is there some interface or method that I can fulfill so that Array.from will work on my class?

Comment: Make the object iterable. Implement `Symbol.iterator`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator

Comment: Note, you could  also just have your class inherit from `Set` and then it would automatically be iterable as the object itself would be an iterable Set with all the methods and capabilities of a `Set` object.

Comment: That's true, you could also upvote beautiful questions from thirsty overflowers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface you are looking for is [iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), which [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) uses. You can simply do

```
class Foo {
  constructor(){
    this.internalList = new Set([1,2,3])
  }
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this.internalList.values();
  }
}
```

The [`values` method of the `Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/values) creates an iterator that we can use here, but you could also implement a custom iterator.